# How do closed and deleted questions affect our site stats?

Tags: discussion

How do closed and deleted questions affect our % Answered ratio? When should we vote to close?

Answer (score 3):

**Voting to close questions is a good thing**.

When you see a question that has comments asking for clarification, and the original poster (OP) doesn't fix the question within a few days, vote to close it as "unclear what you're asking". OP will receive notification about the question being put on hold, which offers a final chance to fix the question. After a few days the status automatically moves to closed, and eventually is automatically deleted.

Closing vague or abandoned questions improves the quality and searchability of the site, as well as our % Answered ratio (as closed questions are removed from the pool).

[This is an excellent overview](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/704/faq-a-guide-to-moderation-voting-to-close-a-question) of deciding when to vote for a question's closure.

And check out [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/294382) if you want to learn exactly when questions are automatically closed and deleted.